# iOS 10 beta, crash when accessing keyboard frame

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, xcode8

iOS 10 Beta 4

Xcode 8 Beta 1

Getting a crash when accessing the keyboard frame size, like so:

```
var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue()
keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
contentInset.top = -keyboardFrame.size.height + (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!
contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!
```

Log shows:

> `[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/`

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Get that same log when focusing on a textview or textfield.

Comment: I am getting this when I touch a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a response from Apple on a private Radar, this was fixed in the production builds of iOS 10.0 and Xcode 8 and later.